# How to @Override an Attribute declared in an Interface implemented in a class

Tags: java, interface, overriding, implementation

Interface:

```
package II_1_b;



public interface Bezeichnung {

public String Bezeichnungi = "Hallo";
public abstract void setBezeichnung();
}
```

class:

```
package II_1_b;

public class Speerwurf extends SportDaten implements Bezeichnung {

private double weite;

 @Override
   public void setBezeichnung(){    //Here we want to Override the String in 
     Bezeichnungi = "Test";         //the Interface
}



public Speerwurf(String n, double w, String bez) {
    super(n);
    this.weite = w;
    bez = Bezeichnungi;
}

@Override
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Speerwurf von " + this.SportlerName + ":\n"
            + weite + " Meter " + Bezeichnungi);
 }

}
```

You can see our Code here, I commented the problem area and hope you can help us. Stackoverflow tells me to add more details, so I'm gonna describe what I'm going to have for lunch: I think I will make myself a TK-Pizza, maybe 2. I'm often very hungry.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you can't. Fields declared in interfaces are inherently `static` and  `final`.

Comment: could you show your class SportDaten?

Answer (score 2):

String Bezeichnungi inherited from the interface into the class is final and hence **cannot** be overridden.

Comment: you don't "inherit" from interfaces. it's accessed through the interface.

Comment: My apologies if i conveyed my point with an incorrect statement. Anyways, thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

As @slaw stated, fields in interfaces cannot be changed and are thus static and final.
Additionally, there is no sense of declaring fields in an interface, because it only declares a certain behaviour and not a state. To make things work like you showed here, you need to use an `abstract` class:

```
package II_1_b;



public abstract class Bezeichnung {

public protected String Bezeichnungi = "Hallo";
public abstract void setBezeichnung();
}
```

Concrete class:

```
package II_1_b;

public class Speerwurf extends Bezeichnung { //think about how to handle SportDaten!

private double weite;

 @Override
   public void setBezeichnung(){    //Here we want to Override the String in 
     Bezeichnungi = "Test";         //the Interface
}



public Speerwurf(String n, double w, String bez) {
    super(n);
    this.weite = w;
    bez = Bezeichnungi;
}

@Override
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Speerwurf von " + this.SportlerName + ":\n"
            + weite + " Meter " + Bezeichnungi);
 }

}
```

Since we dont know your concrete use case, we cannot help you except of telling you why it does not work the way it should